# Group by range of years

Tags: postgresql

I've got a big table (~9M rows) and want to group the rows on a field containing the year. So far that's pretty easy:

```
// greatly simplified:
SELECT count(*), year FROM dataset GROUP BY year ORDER BY 2;
```

We defined some irregular time periods spanning multiple years:

```
<1945, 1946-1964, 1965-1974, 1975-1991, 1992-2005 and >2005
```

I've got no clue on how to group these results in the group by clause. I could make subquery's for every time period.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT count(*) FROM dataset WHERE year <= 1945 AND ...... ) AS pre1945,
  ( ....) AS period2,
  ....
FROM dataset
```

But that feels not right and I'm wondering if it was possible to let Postgresql do it. Especially because the query is a strong simplification of the real query: it has multiple conditions, amongst them a ST_within clause spanning four tables. So choosing the subquery-approach results in a bloated query.

Is there a better way to create this result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use conditional counting:

```
select count(case when year <= 1945 then 1 end) as pre1945,
       count(case when year between 1946 and 1964 then 1 end) as period2,
       count(case when year between 1965 and 1974 then 1 end) as period3,
       ...
from ...
where ...;
```

This works because `count()` ignores null values and the `case` statement returns a `null` for values outside of the range it tests for (an `else null` is implicit).

With the upcoming 9.4 version you can re-write this as

```
select count(*) filter (where year <= 1945) as pre1945,
       count(*) filter (where year between 1946 and 1964) as period2,
       count(*) filter (where year between 1965 and 1974) as period3,
       ...
from ...
where ...;
```

Comment: I never knew I could use conditions within `count()`. It works as expected, although the query itself is very slow. Even with an index on year.

Comment: @stUrb: An index is not going to help as long as you are processing the whole table anyway - unless the index is substantially smaller than the table itself and an index-only scan is possible.

Comment: Hmm thats a pitty. So there is no way to speed it up?

Comment: @stUrb. How could anybody say without knowing *any* relevant details? I suggest you start a new question providing all relevant details. Be sure to read the [tag info for `[postgresql-performance]`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) first.

Comment: Ghehe I reread my comment and thought, how is anyone going to answer that :) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the result as rows in instead of as columns as in @a_horse's answer then create the year ranges in a CTE and join the table to it

```
with years(year_range) as ( values
    (int4range(1900, 1945, '[]')),
    (int4range(1946, 1964, '[]')),
    (int4range(1965, 1974, '[]')),
    (int4range(1975, 1991, '[]')),
    (int4range(1992, 2005, '[]')),
    (int4range(2005, 2014, '[]'))
)
select year_range, count(*)
from
    dataset d
    left join
    years y on d.year <@ y.year_range
group by 1 
order by 1
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html